# An Email Report Application for Outlook

Tags: python, macos, email, outlook, applescript

The sales folk in my start-up send and receive a bunch of mail on a daily basis from vendors. dealers and customers.
But they tend to lose track of these mails quite often...as to whether they have responded/followed-up or not. And they waste a lot of time on figuring this out. 
Expecting them to use a Mail Tool like MailChimp is even more painful and a ticketing tool is not a good fit for the jobs.

Hence, I am trying to build an app that can create a report of the total Email IDs interacted with in a particular date range. The only goal is to create a report, in a csv file or to dump the data into Google spreadsheets.

The report for the period entered by the user would look as below:

1. Email ID  - All emails lying in "sent items" AND "inbox" for particular date range
2. Name - If present
3. Status

The "Status" would be:

1. Received not responded by sales person
2. Sent but not responded by recipient
3. Responded by Sales Person
4. ...and so on

I am vary of running the script directly on the mail server and am not sure if Outlook Exchange would allow something like this.
I would prefer if it could be an application that runs directly on the sales person's machine.

A few use Macs and the others Windows. I would be focussing on the Macs first.
The mail tool used is Outlook for Mac-2011 and the machines are either Lions or Snow Leopards.
Mail is on the Outlook Exchange

I must confess to be not much of a coder, but i blunder/Google my was through it. 
I had some time on my hand with the holiday season coming up, hence thought of taking this project up.

I am moderately comfortable with Python.
But for this project, from what i have read, appears to be the job for AppleScripting.
Before starting my blunderings, i wanted to seek the advice of the SO community on the same:

1. Is AppleScripting the best bet here? If yes, could you share the best resource to read up the same. I have the copy of "AppleScript The Comprehensive Guide to Scripting and Automation on Mac OS X". But it is almsot 6 years old.
2. Could it be done somehow just using Python? - I wanted to dump the respective reports onto Google Spreadsheets, hence would be easier to get Python involved here.
3. Are there any similar applications that are already out there?
4. Or am i completely off track

Sorry for the ramble. But really Looking forward to some assistance on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked:

[AppleScript 1-2-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102119)
and 
[AppleScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102119)

There also some good tutorials here:  [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewforum.php?id=31)

That being said, you should consider the cost/benefit of learning AppleScript to accomplish one task at your company. You may be better off simply hiring someone to write the script for you and focus on growing your business instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on the books. Will definitely give em the shot. You are true on the project being given to someone who knows it. It is just that i thought since i had a bit of time on my hand i could learn applescripting. Thought it might come in handy later.